# How to remove numbers with the same whole part and keep the first occurence from a list?

Tags: c#, list, duplicates, double

I have the following list:

```
data = [293.0, 293.1, 293.5, 390.0, 390.2, 390.4, 391.4]
```

I want to remove the values that have the same whole part and store them into secondary list, and store the first value into a main list.

The result:

```
main = [293.0, 390.0, 391.4]

secondary = [293.1, 293.5, 390.2, 391.4]
```

And here is my program:

```
public static void checkForOverlap(List<double> data)
    {

        List<double> main = new List<double>();
        List<double> secondary = new List<double>();

        //pointer holds the first occured value 
        double pointer;
        bool firstOccurence = true;

        pointer = Convert.ToInt32(data[0]);
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++ )
        {


            if ((data[i] - pointer) < 1 && (data[i] - pointer) == 0 && firstOccurence == true)
            {

                main.Add(data[i]);
                firstOccurence = false;
            }
            if (data[i] > 1)
            {
                pointer = Convert.ToInt32(data[i]);
                firstOccurence = true;
            }
            else {
                secondary.Add(data[i]);      
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the question exactly? What is the exact problem with your code?

Comment: If your code is already working, this question might belong on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault it's only adding the first value of the data list into the main list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is easy to do with LINQ. First, you group the input data by whole integer part:

```
var groups = data.GroupBy(f => (int)f);
```

Then you can simply project from the groups into your main and secondary sequences:

```
var main = groups.Select(g => g.First()).ToList();
var secondary = groups.SelectMany(g => g.Skip(1)).ToList();
```

This is guaranteed to work exactly as you describe because `GroupBy` provides the necessary guarantees (both the groups themselves and the items inside each group will appear when enumerating in the same order your data appears in the input).

Comment: I'd use `Floor` instead of casting to an `int` - `double`s go way beyond `int`'s range.

Comment: And you shouldn't be regrouping in the `secondary` code (you've got `groups.GroupBy(...` right now)

Comment: @TimS.: Thanks, grouping for secondary was a copy/paste error. Regarding the range, I tend to err on the side of caution -- better to get an exception by default rather than risk going into ranges where the accuracy of `double` is less than one whole unit. Granted, all of this is theoretical but it might lead in WTF moments if it happens, while an exception is unmistakable.